# Gstreamer problems network streaming with gst-launch

Tags: networking, streaming, gstreamer, gst-launch

quite new to Gstreamer, but I'm trying to implement a network stream using the gst-launch command. So far I've managed to get the pipeline working with the videotestsrc but when I try to put a filesrc in it's place I have trouble. the following is what I've tried

- Taking a .mov/.mkv file and streaming

  ```
  gst-launch -ve gstrtpbin name=rtpbin filesrc location=/home/user/Gstreamer_projects

  /test_videos/bbb_short_1080p.mkv ! matroskademux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! 

  rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.1.21 port=5000 

  rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.21 port=5001 sync=false async=false udpsrc 

  port=5005 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0
  ```

the output on the terminal is

```
    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

    Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...

     Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...

     New clock: GstSystemClock

     /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0: caps = application/x-rtcp

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin

    /GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:send_rtcp_src: caps = application/x-rtcp

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink1.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtcp

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0

    /GstRtpBin:rtpbin.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad3: caps = application/x-rtcp

    ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.

    Additional debug info:

    matroska-demux.c(4492): gst_matroska_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0
    /GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0:

    stream stopped, reason not-linked

    Execution ended after 1096585 ns.

    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

    Setting pipeline to READY ...

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink1.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0: caps = NULL

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin
    /GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:send_rtcp_src: caps = NULL

     /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0.GstPad:audio_00: caps = NULL

    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0.GstPad:video_00: caps = NULL

    Setting pipeline to NULL ...

    Freeing pipeline ...
```

- Converted the above file into YUV and then streamed this. This works but very slowly at 2-3fps.

If anyone knows how to fix the pipeline to demux the file properly or increase the performance of the x264enc in Gstreamer I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add a queue element before h264parse element. Also, specify the video src pad of matroskademux in the pipeline.